# how to create you tube format media player?

Tags: java, media-player

I can create a normal media player and its work fine. But i need a you tube format media player.

Comment: YouTube doesn't have a format; they use other people's formats.

Comment: ok another doubt how to merge videos name and videos thumbnails at the same time in the list view. i am fresher for this android application help me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tube doesn't have any special format.But you can create media player by using youtube API and much more from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html).

Comment: ok another doubt how to merge videos name and videos thumbnails at the same time in the list view i am fresher for this android application help me

Comment: I recommend you to first of all go through the all docs which are given.And the answer of your question is here : http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the video files from Youtube as FLV files then you can try implemeting playback using [Xuggle](http://www.xuggle.com).

Comment: ok another doubt how to merge videos name and videos thumbnails at the same time in the list view. i am fresher for this android application help me.....